# Horizontal scrollbar for ajax datatable

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

How to add horizontal scrollbar to ajax datatable ? I have tried using "ScrollX" :true, but its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDataTable1').DataTable({       
        "ajax": {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "/DisplayUserProfile",  
            },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "PK_UserProfile" },
            { "data": "UserName" },

        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDataTable1').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true,
        "ajax": {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "/DisplayUserProfile",  
            },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "PK_UserProfile" },
            { "data": "UserName" },

        ]
    } );
} );
```

**Update**
I think the problem is with ajax request so you should add the scrollX after the ajax call. So you can use datatable events to get it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var s= $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5c2cd0ec2e0000de52e877a1',

} );


s.one( 'draw', function () {
   $('#example').DataTable({
       destroy: true,
       "scrollX": true
    });
} );


} );
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/eq7b8h32/)

Answer (score 0):

Using the scrollX parameter should solve the problem. https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDataTable1').DataTable({       
        "ajax": {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "/DisplayUserProfile",  
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "PK_UserProfile" },
            { "data": "UserName" },

        ],
        "scrollX": true
    });
});
```

Comment: Then it would be nice to provide more info. Are you using an old version of DataTables? Do you have general CSS rules to override tables? Or didn't you set the max width of the parent html element? Please provide more code or screenshots.